# Задача из Кернигана-Ричи

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть у тебя маленький буфер и на потоковый ввод поступает строка большего размера чем буфер. В бесконечном цикле проходишь буфером по строке, пока не встретишь символ "\n", тем самым мы узнали ее длину.
Потом хотелось бы считать ее заново уже в новый буфер с подходящим размером.
Как вернуть каретку в начало строки? 
Пробовал putchar('\r')
Задача 1.16

```
int len;                // Длина текущей строки
int max;                // Длина максимальной строки из просмотренных
int current;            // Длина текущей строки
char line[MAXLINE];     // Текущая строка
char longest[MAXLINE];  // Максимальная из предыдущих строк

max = 0;
current = 0;

while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
{
    current +=
        len;                 // Если считанная строка больше MAXLINE, то выделить необходимый размер

    if (line[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
        putchar('\r');
        getline(line, current);
        max = current;
        copy(longest, line);
    }
}

if (max > 0)                         //Была ли хоть одна строка?
    printf("%s \n", longest);    //Печать самой длинной строки

return 0;

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

// copy - копирует строку из 'from' в 'to', 'to' - достаточно большой

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: а добавь код со вводом

Comment: Что значит "считать её заново"? Данные, принятые из stdin, перемотке не подлежат. Поэтому -да, хотелось бы увидеть как именно они вводятся.

Comment: Кстати, если речь о задаче 1.16, то в оригинале она звучит не так, как указано в вопросе. Либо кто-то не так понял условие, либо это просто кривой перевод.

Comment: @PinkTux читаю getchar () с консоли. Т.е. получается вернуться в начало потока уже нельзя после того как из него считал? Задача звучит так: печать самой длинной строки без каких либо ограничений на ее размер!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашей формулировке без динамического распределения памяти задача не решаема в принципе. Но дело в том, что в оригинале задача формулируется по-другому. Сравните, русский перевод:

> Упражнение 1.16. Перепишите main предыдущей программы так, чтобы она
>   могла печатать самую длинную строку без каких-либо ограничений на ее
>   размер.

И оригинал:

> Exercise 1-16. Revise the main routine of the longest-line program so
>   it will correctly print the length of arbitrary long input lines, and
>   as much as possible of the text.

И вот в такой формулировке она уже решается без проблем.

**Вывод: всегда проверяйте входные данные на корректность, и не только в программном коде :-)**

Comment: Спасибо! Как я понял необходимо узнать длину самой длинной строки, независимо от длины буфера. Правильно?

Comment: Да. И вывести максимум от того, что можно из неё добыть (то есть если уместилась целиком - всю, если не уместилось - сколько получится).

Comment: @ActiveNum  да, если читаемая строка не помещается в буфер, то делим его на 2 части и начинаем читать во вторую половину (динамически сдвигая ее начало к середине буфера) так, чтобы в конце получалось что-то в таком духе -- `"это начало строки а ее середина не пом...и вот конец нашей длинной строки\n"` (3 точки в середине вставляет программа) / Попробуйте свои силы.

Answer (score 0):

Не проще ли делать буферу `realloc` по какой нибудь разумной стратегии, например, удваивать его?

Comment: malloc вообще не используется, ограничено условием задачи! char buf[BUF_SIZE], так выделяется память